# Meaning of compilation error : error C2704: __va_start intrinsic only allowed in varargs?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, variadic-functions, win64

I'm using VS2010 Pro compiler, when I build on x64 I get below compilation error. Compiles perfectly on x86.
error C2704: '' : __va_start intrinsic only allowed in varargs

Declaration of method:

```
int foo(char* buf, int maxChar, const char*& fmt);
```

definition:

```
 int foo(char* buf, int maxChar, const char*& fmt)
{
    int numChar = 0;
    if (fmt)
    {
        va_list plist;
        va_start(plist, fmt);
        numChar = _vsnprintf(buf, maxChar, fmt, plist);
        va_end(plist);
    }
    return numChar;
}
```

**What is the meaning of the error? How to fix this?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it means pretty much what it says. The compiler won't allow you to use `va_start`, `va_arg`, etc, except in a variable argument function. Using `va_start` outside of a vararg function makes no sense.

This doesn't define a variable argument function:

```
int foo(char* buf, int maxChar, const char*& fmt)
```

This does:

```
int foo(char* buf, int maxChar, const char*& fmt, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks, why isn't this an issue in x86 compilation?

Comment: @John It might well be a problem, you just don't get a diagnostic.

Comment: My only guess (why you do not get an error message in x86) is a compiler bug.

Answer (score 3):

On x86, all arguments are passed on the stack, and it's semantically safe (albeit incorrect) to use `va_start` and friends to get "arguments".

However, on amd64 (and most likely on ARM), [some arguments are passed via registers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/14/58579.aspx).  In this case, using `va_start` in a function that isn't declared to take variable arguments is semantically unsafe - `va_start` would index into invalid memory.

Answer (score 1):

You used a varargs macro in a function with a fixed number of arguments; [MSDN link to the error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zz611kb%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).